# How to change variable values that are in other project from a select form in other proyect on the same server?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

So I'm developing a web app that based on the selected images it has to change the variables values from other project that stores the path of the images, its like interface to configure the main project that shows the images.

I have the images stored in a folder inside the web app that im developing.
So my approach to solving this is to save the selected images paths to mysql or maybe not use mysql at all i don't know which will be better, then store the paths to an array or variables and then dump them in the main project`s code that is in the same server. Ill show you my form and how the main project gets the images.

I'm kinda new to laravel and web development in general but im not new to coding or mysql im on my last semester of systems engineering and this is for my social service but i really never done anything like this or close to it.
Thanks in advance.

I have read about how to store the images paths and view the images but i just don't know how to update other projects on the same server.

This is my select form

```
<div class="card-header"> Imagen 1 </div>
<img class="card-img-top" id="imgSrcPreview" src="{{ asset('img/noImagen.png') }}"  style="width:220px; height: 130px; ">
 <div class="card-body" >
   <div class="styled-select slate">
     <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
         <label class="input-group-text" >Imagen</label>
  </div>
    <select id = "imgPreview" class="custom-select" >                                                    
     <option selected value="{{ asset('multimedia/1.jpg') }}">Imagen1</option>
     <option value="{{ asset('multimedia/2.JPG') }}">Imagen2</option>
     <option value="{{ asset('multimedia/3.jpg') }}">Imagen3</option>
     <option value="{{ asset('multimedia/4.jpg') }}">Imagen4</option>
     <option value="{{ asset('multimedia/5.jpg') }}">Imagen5</option>

</select>
    </div>
```

and here is how the main proyects gets its images:

```
<script>

        var neutro='img/negro.png';
        var instruccionesImagenes='img/Imagenes_instrucciones.png';
        var imagen1='img/1.jpg';
        var imagen2='img/2.jpg';
        var imagen3='img/3.jpg';
        var imagen4='img/4.jpg';
        var imagen5='img/5.jpg';
        var imagen6='img/6.jpg';
</script>
```

all of this variables are statics values and the goal is to change this values from my project.

I just have to update the var values to the selected ones in my project.

Comment: You would have to store them in database that both projects can access and then pass them to the script.

Comment: So like a function on the main project that query's the new images once it lunched? because the main project does not have like and interface its just like a slide show of images and other stuff that automatically runs the slide show.

Comment: I would just create an identical model on both projects, use them as I normally would with controller and so.
But the catch is, they need to use the same database in `.env` file - unless you wanna toy with raw queries.

Answer (score 0):

Just create an identical model in both projects, connect to the same database and use them as you normally would.

The catch is - they need to use the same database in `.env` file, but you can also use raw queries and `use database_name`, but it would require some tinkering.